# How to handle external resources among different projects hosted by version control?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control, dependency-management

I have two projects which both use jsoup-1.7.3.jar. I put the two projects to ./NBA folder.

```
./NBA/
  - PlayerStatisticViewer/
  - PlayerStatisticReader/
  - jsoup-1.7.3.jar
  - jsoup-1.7.3-javadoc.jar
```

I commit the NBA folder to online version control system.

I modify ./NBA/PlayerStatisticReader/.classpath to use the library in the parent folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../jsoup-1.7.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="../mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

So far so good, Eclipse can recognize the relative path.

Now I want to add javadoc of jsoup-1.7.3.jar.  I use Eclipse to add the doc file and Eclipse added the following to .classpath file.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="../jsoup-1.7.3.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:file:/D:/Documents/NBA/jsoup-1.7.3-javadoc.jar!/"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

I don't know how to change the jar protocol path to relative path. I tried `value="jar:file:../jsoup-1.7.3-javadoc.jar!/"` but it seems not to work. **Does Jar protocol support relative path?**

I'm doing this because I try to make the repository portable that everyone can work on the project in Eclipse as long as s/he checks out the code from the version control without doing any modification.

**Is it the corrrect way to handle external resources among different projects hosted by version control?**

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the corrrect way to handle external resources among different projects hosted by version control?

It is painful way, because you are managing libraries by hand,

Switch to mature dependency manager, go  [**maven**](http://maven.apache.org/)